# Ruby on Rails 5.1 Action on welcome#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to setup a Rails site on windows 10, but this issue keeps on coming up in my application.html.erb view.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Sam's/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20171102-114504-jcayzfjson):
4:     <title>Scotts Oyster Bar</title>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6:
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9:   </head>
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to fix this (I already install nodejs and restarted windows)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yeah, i just did

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a thousand headaches trying to write Ruby on Rails in Windows, I always use an IDE when I'm on a windows machine https://c9.io/ works well and makes things hassle free.

Comment: Im using Jetbrains' RubyMine IDE, but the issue still persists